# Installing node.js with package installer - dyld:Library not loaded error

Tags: node.js

I downloaded the nodeJs package installer for OSX http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.6.5/node-v0.6.5.pkg

But when I run `node` , i receive the following error in the terminal:

```
  dyld: Library not loaded: /opt/local/lib/libssl.0.9.8.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/node
  Reason: image not found
  Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

What could be the reason for this error?

Comment: By the looks of it you are missing some compiler item (I think part of the GCC compiler or a dependcy - memory is hazy), do you have Xcode installed?

Comment: Hmm, not sure if this might help: http://scratching.psybermonkey.net/2010/09/macports-after-installing-git-core-all.html

Comment: Also - you might find it easier to build from source: https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Installation
It's not very complicated and definitely works (I did it a while ago)

Comment: Installing node from source is highly recommended in this situation.  If building from source fails as well, it will give much more useful information.  Also, it's good practice -- depending on your background, playing around with node could mean a lot more time in the shell than you're used to.

Comment: Alright guys thanks for the tip, I'll try to build it from source.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

That error indicates that you are missing libssl.

I have always installed Node using [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/):

```
brew install node
```

Comment: @rocco try:  brew upgrade node

Comment: @NicholasFrancis whow, this was over 5 1/2 years ago. I'm using nvm now.

Comment: Years passing by, but that answer is still useful)

Answer (score 7):

That error indicates that the lib called libssl is not found.

Try to install node if you haven't done so far (Use [Homebrew](https://brew.sh))

```
brew install node
```

or if you have then just update.

```
brew upgrade node
```

Answer (score 4):

20210118, my worked solution is:

`brew reinstall npm`

Comment: This worked for me, I think OS upgrade keeps breaking my development environment.

Answer (score 2):

I think multiple causes are behind this issue and while reinstalling node definitely helps, perhaps we should also figure out what's the missing library.

The author is missing libssl apparently but in my case it was **icu4c**.

```
$ npm
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/icu4c/lib/libicui18n.60.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/opt/node@8/bin/node
  Reason: image not found
Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

And was solved as below.

```
brew uninstall icu4c
brew reinstall node --without-icu4c
```

This thread will give you an insight.
https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/11713

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't installed MacPorts, install it from http://www.macports.org/install.php.
To fix the issue of libssl, install **openssl**

```
sudo port install openssl@0.9.8
```

If you have already installed the latest the version of openssl, you will have to deactivate it and install 0.9.8. For that please follow the instrucations in this page.
http://scratching.psybermonkey.net/2010/09/macports-after-installing-git-core-all.html

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting something like this when starting a node service

dyld[1101]: Library not loaded:

On mac os.
Try and install/reinstall node again... brew install node