# Trying to start my server on a Node project, but getting this error

Tags: node.js, dyld

I'm trying to start a Node.js project that I did for my boot camp, and I'm getting this error back:

dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/icu4c/lib/libicui18n.58.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/node
  Reason: image not found

I downloaded High Sierra recently, but I don't know if this would do anything.

Comment: Have you tried `brew update` and `brew upgrade`?

Comment: Wow, that worked. I thought I had tried everything with brew. I feel dumb, hahaha. Thanks!

Comment: Don't feel dumb, it happens to us all :)

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you just needed to update your brew:

```
brew update
brew upgrade
```

Comment: EXCELLENT!! tHat worked and its nice and clean.  Some of these other work arounds seem like they might have side effects (bad?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8455432/installing-node-js-with-package-installer-dyldlibrary-not-loaded-error)